# Syntax for list delimiters in template

Tags: templates, language-agnostic, delimiter

I'm writing an application that allows the user to configure the output using templates. For example:

---

Variables:

```
name = "BoppreH"
language = "Python"
```

Template:

```
My name is {name} and I like {language}.
```

Output:

```
My name is BoppreH and I like Python.
```

---

This works fine for simple data, like strings and numbers, but I can't find a good syntax for *lists*, more specifically for their delimiters.

```
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "watermelon"]

I like {???}.

I like banana, apple, watermelon.
```

In this case the desired delimiter was a comma, but how can the user specify that? Is there some template format with this feature?

I'm more concerned about making the syntax simple to understand, regardless of language or library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement filters, and require their use for non-scalar types.

```
I like {fruits|join:", "}.
```

Comment: I like this answer for being concise and extremely flexible, but I'm worried about performance. Nevertheless, I find it the best so far.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a list contains an unknown number of members, and sometimes variables/placeholders of its own.  An example might be listing the name of a person along with their phone numbers.  The desired output might look something like this:

```
John Doe
555-1212
555-1234
```

In a templating system that supported this, you'd need two types of variables: One that designated a placeholder for a value (like the curly braces you're using now), and another to denote the start and end of the list.  So, something like this:

```
{name}
{{phone_numbers}}{phone}{{/phone_numbers}}
```

Your array of values might look like this:

values = [names: "John Doe", phone_numbers: [ phone: "555-1212", phone: "555-1234"]]

Each value in the "phone_numbers" array would create a new instance of everything that existed between {{phone_numbers}} and {{/phone_numbers}}, placing the values contained within those two "tags".

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but the questioner was asking how to allow for a user-specified delimiter in the template, no?  Typically with such systems, the user builds and formats the template, and the programmer builds the code to populate the template, so a user-specified delimiter would be part of the template created by the user.  In my example above, the delimiter was a newline, hence each phone number is listed on its own line.  Or is the "user" in this case the one writing the code to populate the template?  If so, that's what I misunderstood.